# How do I close the intellisense menu in Visual Studio without selecting anything?

Tags: visual-studio

When ever I typed a letter, the `intellisense` in visual studio will pop up a drop down function list. When I press tab, it would choose the function. press right, it would come out a bracket. I would like to ask how could I escape from the `intellisense`. I need to use mouse to click someplace in VS in order not to choose the function. It's very trouble. Is there any hot key that could escape from the `intellisense` and close the drop down list?

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: you can check their behavior [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1081471/why-is-intellisense-support-for-c-sharp-lacking-when-compared-to-vb-net) [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ecfczya1(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To "***escape*** from the intellisense" (your words, emphasis mine), you press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, i.e. "Escape".

Comment: Shouldn't that be obvious if you ever used any sane software?

Comment: @DominicKexel one would think

Comment: I am a newbie. Thank you for your help.

Comment: This sounds odd, but what do I do if escape doesn't close it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this mechanism is easy to unintentionally undo if you declare a custom keybinding that uses escape. I tried to set up escape shift+, and escape shift+. to go to the top and bottom of the file. It's an old Emacs habit. I had to get rid of it, though when I realized that it prevented Esc from closing the Intellisense popups.

Comment: This often does not work. Using Visual Studio 2015, this randomly does not work about 70% of the time. Nothing at all happens when I press Esc. Then pressing Esc will work for a short while, but will soon stop working again. This is also the case when trying to use Esc in the Find and Replace search window.

Comment: @def It appears to be fixed in 16.9.2. https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/Escape-sometimes-no-longer-cancels-inlin/1305335